# Solving a specific equation in Mathematica & Finding the range of a value in an inequality

Tags: mathematical-optimization, education

Is there any way to solve (or even approximate the value of x) the following equation in Mathematica?

```
Solve[x - 11 - (1.0002)(0.0011/5.001)^(3x/(3x-5.0001)) == 0, x, Reals]
```

I have also another question which is in the following inequality how can I find the range of m that satisfies the inequality?

```
m - 2 - (0.02/5)^(m/(m-2)) > 0 && m > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one works the way you have written unless `x` has some definition that breaks it.
Try `Remove[x]` and then evaluate it again.

For the second one write:

```
Reduce[m - 2 - (2/100/5)^(m/(m - 2)) > 0 && m > 0, m, Reals]
```

> m > 2

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. For the first equation whenever I try to solve it I faced the following message: "Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

Comment: Try this `Solve[Rationalize[
   x - 11 - (1.0002) (0.0011/5.001)^(3 x/(3 x - 5.0001)) == 0], x, 
  Reals] // N[#, 10] &`

Comment: Thank you so much @RohitNamjoshi. It works perfectly.